# wxpython Ultimatelistctrl, how to change colour of selected item?

Tags: wxpython

When a row is selected in ULC but it doesn't have focus (i.e selecting a row, then opening a dialog) the colour scheme of the highlighted row, light grey text with a slightly darker background is rather difficult to read. How can I darken the text in this circumstance? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible way - but I don’t know if it will work - is to use the SetItemTextColour method for ULC, on each item:

https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.lib.agw.ultimatelistctrl.UltimateListCtrl.html#wx.lib.agw.ultimatelistctrl.UltimateListCtrl.SetItemTextColour

This should force the text colour to be always the same, but I haven’t tested it.

Another possibility is to enable “Vista” selection style (maybe), by doing:

ListCtrl.EnableSelectionVista(True)

Comment: It would be useful to know how to modify the standard colours, I can see how to modify the Vista colours as they are RGB values but I cannot locate the others...